# NSMutableURLRequest response null

Tags: objective-c, xcode, post, nsmutableurlrequest

I am trying to make a POST request with encrypted string using following code. In response I get null from server. I test with this https://www.hurl.it using same value and get 200. Can't figure out where is the problem.

To encode string I have use

NSUTF8StringEncoding
NSASCIIStringEncoding
NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding

```
forD = @"AAAAAAAAAMCYdiQv+wcAsBAAAAAAAAAAaQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKTkVXIEpFUlNFWTEZMBcGA1UEChMQVkVSSVpPTiBXSVJFTEVTUzENMAsGA1UECxMETUlQUzEbMBkAAAAAAAAAwAAAAAAAAADACABUSUNTLTAxAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABUfCQv+wcA8L4GJC/7BwAABQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA1ZwkL/sHAFCDeyQv+wcQAA==";

NSData* requestData = [forD dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseURL]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:@"1" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Appversion"];
[request setValue:@"*/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"gzip,deflate" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];

[request setHTTPBody: requestData];

NSLog(@"%@", [request allHTTPHeaderFields]);
NSLog(@"%@", [request HTTPBody]);

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *receivedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSLog(@"\n\n === RESPONSE SERVER ==== \n\n %@",[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:0 error:nil]);
```

Comment: have you checked what you get from your NSError parameter?

Comment: no error. getting (null) while print receiveData @Bozzy

Comment: What do you get logging the `receivedData` without trying to JSON deserialize it?

Comment: Both `receivedData` and `error` are nil from the `sendSynchronousRequest` statement?

Comment: What does: "To encode string I have use

NSUTF8StringEncoding NSASCIIStringEncoding NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding" mean?

Comment: @Shohrab What do you get when you print "response" after sendSynchronousRequest?

Comment: @all when i tried to print receivedData without JSON deserialize it shows nil.

Comment: Debug steps missing: Print `receivedData` instead. Check `error`. Use the `error` parameter of `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:`. Check the console, you do have App Transport Security enable?

Comment: I tested with `NSString *baseURL = @"https://www.hurl.it";`, I got `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">\n<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>\n<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>\n<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>` for the answer. (using `NSLog(@"data as UTF8Str: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);`)